# Laravel overwrite toArray with custom parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller I have:

```
$Locations = Locations::where(something);       
$Locations->get()->toArray(true);
```

And inside the model:

```
function toArray($include_all = false) {
   var_dump($include_all);
}
```

The include all variable is false, although the function gets called.
Is there a reason why it's doing that ?

I want to call a custom toArray because I have more oneToMany relations with different structures that I want to change (some of them are serialized for example)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Illuminate\Support\Collection` methods such as `map()` and `filter()` to modify the collection and at the end of that call `toArray()` method.

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to use the ->map() every time I do the database query, I wanted to do it inside the toArray() function of the model  so I wont have to duplicate the code

Comment: you can write a function that has all logic, for example:
`function myFunc($arg) { return // mapping logic}`
`Model::someQuery()->get()->map('myFunc')->toArray();`

Job of `toArray()` is only convert collection of items to array, no more.

Comment: It should also be noted that `->get` always returns an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Furthermore, `->toArray()` is a method provided by `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and therefore overwriting it does not seem like a sane approach. The mapping does seem like the correct way to go here.

Comment: And how can I change an array value inside the map function? I see that it works to change a string value, but not an array

Comment: You can and able to change and modify any data type in map functions, and return modified value inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly easy to overwrite, however I think there is some confusion that should be cleared up first.

First, the `toArray()` method you are calling in this case is on the `Collection` which is the object which is returned when you use `get()` on your model.

With that said, you can add the following to your `Location` model to return a custom collection...

```
public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    return new CustomCollection($models);
}
```

Then you write the new `CustomCollection` class with appropriate namespaces just to make sure it gets auto loaded fine, have it extend `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and then you can proceed to override the `toArray` method.

However, it feels like you randomly selected this `toArray()` as a proper candidate to perform your logic just because you are already using it.  You should think about creating a new function which calls `$this->toArray()` to grab the results and modify them as you need and return that.

If you need this same functionality on other models, just keep adding that `newCollection` method where needed.

This is also in the docs as well, might be worth checking out...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections#custom-collections